# Image positioning responsive design

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to position an image on top of another image using transform:

```
position: absolute;
translate(65vw, -40vh);
```

When I resize the view port the image doesn't stay put.

How would I place a small image on a larger canvas and ensured it stayed put when I resized the view port?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean? like position fixed?

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to put waldo on a where's waldo game board. I decided to put waldo on the game board because I thought it would be easier than checking the xy coordinates of the mouse all the time. Now, waldo has to stay in the same spot no matter what the screen size. Waldo is also a seperate image.

Comment: Post what you have tried, and then you may get help.

Comment: I have. Transform: Translate()

Comment: We need a full working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To position the element use left and top, to position the center of the element at the desired point use translate. Try something like this:

```
position: absolute;
left:65vw
top:40vh;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```